# dSPACE MicroAutoBox-PWM-Generation

Tags: matlab, simulink, dspace-ecu

I have a problem with the so-called MicroAutoBox 2 with the DIO that when i genrate a PWM signal, then the signal remains almost at 0V, but if I change the duty cycle or frequency then the shape of the signal changes. and I also tried to set a pin on HIGH but also without success. i am sure that i have selected the right pins. The MAB is DS1505 and DS1507. to my question: what could be my mistake that the DIO dose not work ?

Model:

[image: Model]

Signal:

[image: Signal]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @PhilGoddard why dose not DIO work ? )